# Lollipop back and up navigation differences

Tags: android, android-navigation

I'm using Lollipop with Toolbar as my action bar. The toolbar shows the navigation 'up' button, and the activities all have their parent activity specified in the manifest. The use case is very simple, there is the main activity Main (action MAIN, category LAUNCHER), and it contains a list whose items, when clicked, start another activity B.

When the navigation up button is pressed, the onDestroy(), followed by onCreate() methods are called on the MAIN activity, which means the already existing instance is replaced by a new one. B.finish() is not called.

When the back button is clicked, first the B.finish() method is called, then only onResume() is called.

This results in slight differences in my apps behavior, but nothing complex, can be fixed. The other differences are that the 'up' navigation triggers a transition which looks as if the Main activity was started explicitly (incomplete slide from the bottom by default), whereas the back button reverses the transition of the B enter activity (so incomplete slide downwards by default).

All of it is something I can live with, I would just like to understand why this is and if there is a bug somewhere in my application, or if I am supposed to do something about it.